# For-loops with same output and number of iterations differ in execution time

Tags: c, loops

Why is the first loop faster than the second loop?

For me the second loop seems less expensive, because there is no mathematical expression in the body to compute. But still I get a time limit exceed on spoi.com ([AP2](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AP2/)) for that second loop. The first loop does get accepted however.

Both for-loops print the same finite arithmetic progression. For example:

```
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
```

Given:

```
long long n; // number of members in series ( 8 in above example )
long long d; // constant distance between the members ( 2 in example )
long long start; // first member in series ( 1 )
long long end; // last member in series ( 15 )
```

First loop:

```
for(long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lld ", start+(i*d));
```

Second loop:

```
for(long long i = start; i <= end; i+=d) 
        printf("%lld ", i);
```

My thoughts on that:

It seems to me that the incrementation by 1 and the multiplication in the first loop is less expensive than the incrementation by `d` in the second loop, because GCC does some optimization on the expressions?

---

So, I did a "benchmark" on my computer with the following code, and I can not say which loop is faster. It's rather random.

So now my conclusion is, that the code review on spoj.com for [AP2](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AP2/) is somehow arbitrary.

```
#define NUM_MEMBERS 2000000LL
#define DISTANCE 3LL
#define START 1000000LL

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t begin, finish;
    double time1, time2;

    long long n = NUM_MEMBERS;
    long long d = DISTANCE;
    long long start = START;
    long long end = START+((NUM_MEMBERS-1)*DISTANCE);

    begin = clock();
    for(long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lld ", start+(i*d));
    finish = clock();
    time1 = (double)(finish-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    begin = clock();
    for(long long i = start; i <= end; i+=d)
        printf("%lld ", i);
    finish = clock();
    time2 = (double)(finish-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\ntime1: %g\ntime2: %g\n", time1, time2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please benchmark properly and provide the information with a [mcve]. Have a look at the Assembler code. The code might even be the same. Anyway, the `printf` takes much more time than any of the calculations.

Comment: Who says which one is faster? Did you even compile your code optimized?

Comment: On my computer I compile without optimization flags. But I don't know if `gcc` on spoj.com uses them.